# Rest Assured Vs. Apache HttpClient performance

Tags: rest-api, rest-assured

I am checking Rest Assured now, and want to understand its performance.
So, I created 2 unit tests:

```
public static final String C_URL = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/2017/circuits.json";

@Test
public void test_getCircuitsFor2017Season_only() {

    System.out.println("test_getCircuitsFor2017Season_only");

    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    given().
    when().
    get(C_URL);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

}


@Test
public void test_apache4() {

    System.out.println("test_apache4");

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(C_URL);
    try {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And the results are:

```
test_apache4
223
test_getCircuitsFor2017Season_only
1027
```

Is it a fair test? Can performance be improved for Rest Assured?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are not unit tests as your testing a remote site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a fair test?

Not really.

- Performance tests usually involve warm-up phase as anonygoose suggested in his/her answer. For instance, in case of HTTP clients this is to let them start thread and HTTP connection pools.
- Performance tests should sent many requests over time. If you're sending only one request you might be simply out of lack as the server or network can be busy at this particular moment.
- REST-assured is a wrapper around Apache HTTP Client so you could expect that only overhead is to translate your requests to calls to HTTP client and response back. However, REST-assured might be using a different version of Apache HTTP client than you did. Also, Apache HTTP client has tens of configuration parameters to tune its performance. It could be the reason that the configuration you have used is different than the default configuration used by REST-assured. Finally, by default REST-assured creates a new Apache HTTP Client instance for each REST-assured call.

> Can performance be improved for Rest Assured?

Probably yes. You can:

- Tune Apache HTTP Client instance.  See [`HttpClientConfig#httpClientFactory`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.2/io/restassured/config/HttpClientConfig.html#httpClientFactory-io.restassured.config.HttpClientConfig.HttpClientFactory-) for more details how to configure Apache HTTP client instance in REST-assured.
- Force REST-assured to reuse HTTP Client instance. See [`HttpClientConfig#reuseHttpClientInstance`](https://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.2/io/restassured/config/HttpClientConfig.html#reuseHttpClientInstance--) for details.
- Run profiling on REST-assured and submit pull requests with improvements :-) REST-assured uses Groovy which, as the author suggests, [may impact its performance](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rest-assured/performance%7Csort:date/rest-assured/LQ5jHHOwgYE/CEqM4z55NAUJ).

There's also one question you haven't asked:

> Why is it important to have fast tests with REST-assured?

Comment: "Why is it important to have fast tests with REST-assured?" :) From my side I was checking Rest Assured vs. an in-house rest framework performance. After all, I wouldn't want to use a very slow tool if I have a faster one.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51519306/rest-assured-extremely-slow-at-the-first-get-post-request) question Rest Assured is pretty slow on the first request you make.  Looks like it has to warm up a little for some reason.

I've tested version 4.0 of Rest Assured myself, and this appears to be the case. The first request is 2000ms+, then every subsequent request in the same suite is 200-300ms.

A counter question might be: why compare them?  Rest Assured is for testing API requests and is extremely rich in terms of features and ability.  The HttpClient from apache is for making requests and comes with none of the testing features.

If you are making requests in order to test them, use Rest Assured.  If you're making requests as a means to an end, use HttpClient.

Comment: So you suggest that to use Rest Assured I should accept performance degradation as a side affect?

Comment: I think it's a reasonable trade-off for the testing capabilities that Rest Assured provides.  With further experimentation it appears to be slower on the first request per test run, not suite.  So if you're running 10s/100s of suites at the same time, the large delay is only seen once.  While even 2 seconds per test run may not be ideal to you, you'll spend far more time making your own API testing framework around HttpClient if you don't use a pre-built one.

It may be worth asking the creators of Rest Assured about the delay.  There's always the chance that it could be improved.

Comment: Thanks anonygoose!